# How to expand wildard properly with Ansible shell module

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, special-characters

I am trying to run the following command with the Ansible shell module. This same command works fine in a remote shell but I get the following error in Ansible:

```
- name: "Searching coincidendences for literal stratum 70 in /var/log/required.log and /var/log/required.1"
  shell: "ls /var/log/required.log?(.1) | xargs grep -i 'stratum 70' |wc -l"
  args: 
    executable: /bin/bash
```

This is the error message with ansible -vvvv:

```
fatal: [node_test]: FAILED! => {                                                                                                            
    "changed": true,                                                                                                                                         
    "cmd": "ls /var/log/required.log?(.1) | xargs grep -i 'stratum 70' |wc -l",                                                                    
    "delta": "0:00:00.005635",                                                                                                                               
    "end": "2021-07-12 17:50:52.370057",                                                                                                                     
    "invocation": {                                                                                                                                          
        "module_args": {                                                                                                                                     
            "_raw_params": "ls /var/log/required.log?(.1) | xargs grep -i 'stratum 70' |wc -l",                                                    
            "_uses_shell": true,                                                                                                                             
            "argv": null,                                                                                                                                    
            "chdir": null,                                                                                                                                   
            "creates": null,                                                                                                                                 
            "executable": null,                                                                                                                              
            "removes": null,                                                                                                                                 
            "stdin": null,                                                                                                                                   
            "stdin_add_newline": true,                                                                                                                       
            "strip_empty_ends": true,                                                                                                                        
            "warn": true                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                    
    },                                                                                                                                                       
    "msg": "non-zero return code",                                                                                                                           
    "rc": 2,                                                                                                                                                 
    "start": "2021-07-12 17:50:52.364422",                                                                                                                   
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected",                                                                                                  
    "stderr_lines": [                                                                                                                                        
        "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected"                                                                                                         
    ],                                                                                                                                                       
    "stdout": "",                                                                                                                                            
    "stdout_lines": []           **strong text**                                                                                                                            
}
```

It seems that the problem is with the wildcards  *`?(.1)`* to replace characters but i don't know how to escape properly

Comment: Is that supposed to be an extended glob? Or is there an actual set of parens in the filename?

Comment: @PaulHodges. That is exactly what i want to do. I am trying to extract information from the required.log and required.log.1

Comment: Silly question, I see the `-name:` comment now.

Answer (score 1):

Extended globbing must be declared it inside the block.
For that I tend to prefer a block scalar.

```
- name: "Searching coincidendences for literal stratum 70 in /var/log/required.log and /var/log/required.1"
  shell: |
    shopt -s extglob;
    grep -i 'stratum 70' /var/log/required.log?(.1) | wc -l
  args: 
    executable: /bin/bash
```

I don't think you really need it though -

```
- name: "Searching coincidendences for literal stratum 70 in /var/log/required.log and /var/log/required.1"
  shell: "shopt -s extglob; grep -i 'stratum 70' /var/log/required.log?(.1) | wc -l"
  args: 
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Was there some reason you needed the `ls`?

Comment: Haven't tested this as I'd like - check it carefully.

Comment: The first solution you post works, thanks. I use ls and xargs because i didn´t know that grep do the same in one command and of course the use of shorts command.